# Can C# GC move memory objects

Tags: c#

Let's suppose this very basic C# code:

```
var tab = new int[10];
```

I have read that non fixed variables can be moved in memory by garbage collector.

My question is: Is it possible that "tab" address change during my program execution ?

I just want to understand.

In fact, no matter if tab value change.

Comment: Follow up question: why do you care? Just interested?

Comment: I have never understood this sites mentality on questions like this? He mentions in the question that he just wanted to understand the underlying workings. But almost every answer still tells OP that it doesn't matter, he shouldn't care.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it will.

But you can use the [`fixed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement) keyword to stop the GC from moving it if you so desire.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. The memory address of `tab` can be (and most probably will be) changed. Reference: [ECMA-334 C# Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm), chapter [23.4](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf#page=436).

The point is, in C# you don't need to bother about memory addresses as it's a managed language. All references to `tab` variable will be changed accordingly, and your program will survive garbage collection seamlessly.

Answer (score 3):

It is certain that the array object could be moved in memory.

But note that you cannot obtain the pointer of a managed reference object, or you use a `fixed` block, it cannot be moved by GC within it.

If the array object is moved, the reference from variable `tab` to the array object is also fixed by GC, so there would be no way for you to see anything impacted by GC.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using `var` it means you are defining it in a method. Your variable lives in the context of that method for a very short time, and it is very unlikely that GC will move it.

On the other hand GC will move memory blocks to reduce memory fragmentation so yes it may move your variables. Best part of it you will not even notice it since it is same old "tab" for you.

If you want to be sure to fix location of that variable you can use "fixed".